# Jekyll Serve does not load images and assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll

I am running locally my site using the `bundle exec jekyll liveserve` command. The command line shows below that the site is running in `http://127.0.0.1:4000/`

[image]

However, when I visit the site using localhost, it shows internal server error. The images and asset are not loaded.

[image]

In the _config.yml file, the url and baseurl is set as below.

```
url                      : "http://localhost:4000"
baseurl                  : ""
```

I have published the site with github-pages and it works perfectly there but not loading properly locally. Here is the repo [link](https://github.com/setu1421/my-portfolio).